# How is "goes" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

When i was younger, my teacher said the word 'goes' must be pronounced go with an -s sound. But a couple of days ago, my teacher fixed me about that and told me i must pronounce 'goes' the same way we say 'does'. So which one is correct? Thank you!

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/does - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/goes

Comment: AmE: The ending consonant sound is the same in _goes_ as in _does._  The vowel sound is not the same.

Comment: @Adam: Same in BrE.

Answer (score 5):

"Goes" is pronounced "goze", that is, long-o, hard "z" at the end.

"Does" is pronounced "duzz", that is, a short-u sound, hard "z" at the end.

If you go to the pages for these words on thefreedictionary.com, there's a speaker icon you can click which will pronounce the words for you.

Compare these to, say, "gross", which has a long-o, but a soft "s" at the end.

The two do not rhyme.

Answer (score 4):

- **does**: /dʌz/ (strong form) or /dəz/ (weak form)
- **goes**: /gəʊz/

The strong form of "*does*" has the same vowel sound as "*sun*".

The word "*goes*" has the same vowel sound as "*nose*".

Both words end in in a /z/ sound, not with /s/.